# Абстрактный класс. Наследование

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

Допустим, планируется какая-то система классов, например, устройств. У каждого устройства есть некоторые общие члены, например имя устройства, его UUid и другие. Так же есть общие методы, например, методы `set()` и `get()` для доступа к **private** полям, причем, реализация их тоже одинаковая.

Отсюда вопрос - могу ли я в абстрактном классе реализовать эти методы, и *наследовать* их в дочерних классах вместе с реализацией? Это сэкономило бы много времени, много строчек кода, было бы удобнее добавлять новые методы - просто добавить их в родительский класс. Если можно, с небольшим примером. Я попытался это сделать, у меня как-то не вышло. Спасибо.

Привожу пример как я пытался сделать это:

файл *device.h* - базовый абстрактный класс.

```
    #pragma once
    #ifndef DEVICE_H
    #define DEVICE_H

    #include <QString>
    #include <QUuid>

    class Device {

        QString name;
        QString place;
        QUuid id;

    public:

        virtual ~Device() = 0;

        void setName(const QString& new_name);
        const QString& getName() const;

        void setPlace(const QString& new_place);
        const QString& getPlace() const;

        void setUuid(const QUuid& new_id);
        const QUuid& getUuid() const;

    };
    #endif // DEVICE_H
```

файл *device.cpp* - реализация некоторых его методов.

```
#include <device.h>

Device::~Device() {}

void Device::setName(const QString& new_name) {
    this->name = new_name;
}
const QString& Device::getName() const {
    return this->name;
}

void Device::setPlace(const QString& new_place){
    this->place = new_place;
}
const QString& Device::getPlace() const {
    return this->place;
}

void Device::setUuid(const QUuid& new_id){
    this->id = new_id;
}
const QUuid& Device::getUuid() const{
    return this->id;
}
```

файл *sensor.h* - наследник базового класса, в который добавляется еще один член класса и функции доступа к нему.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SENSOR_H
#define SENSOR_H

#include <device.h>

class Sensor : public Device {

    QString name = "Deault_sensor_name";
    QString place = "Default_sensor_place";
    QUuid id = 0x0;
    bool is_alarm = false;

public:

    Sensor();
    Sensor(const QString& new_name, const QString& new_place, const QUuid new_id);
    Sensor(const Sensor& sensor);

    ~Sensor();


    void setAlarm(const bool& alarm_status);
    bool getAlarm() const;

};

#endif // SENSOR_H
```

файл *sensor.cpp* - реализация.

```
#include <sensor.h>

Sensor::Sensor(){}
Sensor::Sensor(const QString& new_name, const QString& new_place, const QUuid new_id){
    this->name = new_name;
    this->place = new_place;
    this->id = new_id;
}
Sensor::Sensor(const Sensor& sensor){
    this->name = sensor.getName();
    this->place = sensor.getPlace();
    this->id = sensor.getUuid();
}

Sensor::~Sensor(){}

void Sensor::setAlarm(const bool& alarm_status){
    this->is_alarm = alarm_status;
}
bool Sensor::getAlarm() const{
    return this->is_alarm;
}
```

Т.е. есть базовый класс `Device`, в котором реализованы методы `set()` и `get()` для некоторых приватных полей. Далее, класс `Sensor` наследуется от класса `Device`. В нем добавляется поле `is_alarm` и методы доступа к нему. Однако, все остальные члены остаются - имя, местоположение, Uuid. И доступ к ним, собственно, осуществляется таким же образом. Этот код не работает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: не знаю сможете вы или нет, но это  возможно

Comment: Вы лучше покажите, что вы попробовали (код), и как именно у вас не получилось. На словах лично мне не совсем понятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat сейчас добавлю в вопрос код

Comment: Вы зачем-то заново декларируете новый, независимый набор членов `name`, `place` и `id` в классе-наследнике `Sensor`. Зачем? Не надо этого делать.

Comment: @AnT они в _private_ секции и не наследуются, как я понял.

Comment: Они наследуются, только прямого доступа к ним нет. Следует инициализировать через параметры конструктора, а выставлять новое значение через сеттеры типа `setName`,  не дублировать все заново.

Comment: @Иван: Что значит "не наследуются"? Наследуются, разумеется. (В любом случае, как вы ожидали это будет работать, если вы в наследнике объявили совсем другие поля?) Для вашего случая, возможно, правильнее было бы сделать эти поля `protected`, а не `private`.

Comment: Вы с самого начала все делаете не так

Comment: @VTT  дело было именно в этом, спасибо, что быстро нашли ошибку и поправили!

Comment: @ARHovsepyan можно узнать, что именно я делаю не так?

Comment: @AnT вам спасибо тоже! всем плюсанул

Answer (score 2, accepted):

кажется вы хотели получить что то типа:

```
class Device {

    QString name;
    QString place;
    QUuid id;
public:
    Device(const QString& n, const QString& p, const QUuid i)
        : name(n), place(p), id(i) {}
    virtual ~Device() = default;
    virtual void setName(const QString& new_name)   { name = new_name; }
    virtual const QString& getName() const          { return name; }
    virtual void setPlace(const QString& new_place) { place = new_place; }
    virtual const QString& getPlace() const         { return place;  }
    virtual void setUuid(const QUuid& new_id)       { id = new_id;   }
    virtual const QUuid& getUuid() const            { return id;     }

};
class Sensor : public Device {
    bool is_alarm = false;
public:
    Sensor(const QString& new_name = "Deault_sensor_name",
           const QString& new_place = "Default_sensor_place", const QUuid new_id = 0)
        : Device(new_name, new_place, new_id) {}
    void setAlarm(const bool& alarm_status) { is_alarm = alarm_status; }
    bool getAlarm() const                   { return  is_alarm; }

};
```

Не нужно обьявлять деструктор чисто виртуальным, не нужно заново дублировать все поля базового класса, не нужен  .cpp файл для такого тривиального  класса, не нужно определять копирующий конструктор, если он будет работать как генерированный конструктор копирования по умолчанию и наконец,  только для читабельноси и  избавления от лишней писанины, не нужно каждый раз  указывать что  это члены  данного обьекта:  `name` и `this->name` это одно и то же

Comment: Если я не объявлю какую-либо функцию чисто виртуальной, тогда я смогу создать объект класса `Device`, что мне не нужно. Возможно, стоит объявить какую-либо другую функцию чисто виртуальной? Про дублирование полей я уже понял. За остальные замечания - большое спасибо, как и за приведенный пример.

Comment: Все зависит от того, чего вы хотите добываться, поскольку можно конструкторы базового класса сделать защищенным и таким образом исключить создание  обьектов , и только производные классы смогут это сделать, можно обьявить любую функцию чисто виртуальным. Подходить к вопросу можно по разному.  Что то мне подсказывает, что вам нужно все функции  сделать чисто виртуальными, а поля защищенными, и уже в производном классе определять как  изменять и получать данные. Но это всего лишь догадки, поскольку я так и не понел  зачем вам нужен такой базовый класс...